# Multiple static target position estimate

Tags: navigation, opencv, estimation, tracking, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An aerial vehicle captures images of the ground, using a down facing camera, in order to detect some static ground targets. Using opencv I created a node that detects those targets and converts their position from the image frame to the world frame. Since all targets are on the ground, each sample is a 3D vector (x,y,0). Note: Using robot_localization I also have the attitude and heading of the aerial vehicle.

What's the best approach to estimate the position of the targets from multiple readings?

Is there a package that implements something to this effect? This is basically a problem of noise removal and estimation, so strategies one of the possible strategies is using clustering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224882/multiple-static-target-position-estimate/) by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2016-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a job that could  be performed by [hector_object_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_object_tracker). It allows for tracking objects both with unique or ambiguous IDs. A example of use is [this video of autonomous exploration](https://youtu.be/Q_ChNVIsmeE?t=6m56s). The robot detects QR codes (unique ID) in the environment as well simulated victims (based on heat, ambiguous). The former are visible as blue markers, the latter as red ones. [This is the launch file used](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_worldmodel/blob/catkin/hector_object_tracker/launch/object_tracker.launch).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on 2016-01-23**:
What I am searching for is more a solution to the position estimation (noise/outlier filtering and estimation to be precise), since I already detect and convert the dected position to the world referencial frame. However hector_object_tracker, doesn't seem to allow access to the filtering side alone

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-01-23**:
It's using EKFs behind the scenes, so it would be up to you to generate appropriate covariance data for your observations (which could be generated also from your robot_localization vehicle pose estimate).

**Comment by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on 2016-01-28**:
One of my problems is that I can't seem to understand how to setup the packge properly and there are no tutorials or extra information. Do you know of  place where I can read more in depth about that package?